# Question based on complex integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to solve this question

$$ I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\iota z t}}{1+z^2} dz $$

Comment: Use   $z=x+iy$, use then substitution, or $z=e^{i\phi}$ and use substitution also

Comment: For $R > 0$, integrate around a semicircular contour of radius $R$ using the residue theorem. Take $R \to \infty$.